# BLE background scanning stops after working for more than an hour

Tags: ionic-framework, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

An Ionic app that scans for BLE tags while running in the background.

The problem is that the app stops scanning for BLE devices after running for more than an hour.

I would like the app to run for a long time without being killed.

Also if the phone has a lock screen password the app stops scanning for BLE devices sooner than when the phone doesn't have a lock screen password

Comment: Modern phones are using extensive battery-saving measurements to prevent apps from running indefinitely in the background. Are you using Android or iOS?

Comment: I'm using Android OS. In the Battery Optimization Settings, the app is set to Not Optimize. Also, I'm using Wake Lock to keep the device screen on while scanning.